# macOS launch jar file by double clicking

Tags: java, macos, jar

I have an executable jar file that executes just fine on my macOS system via the following command:

```
java -jar Hello.jar
```

However, when I try to double click on it, it pauses and then eventually shows a popup dialog saying

> The Java JAR file "Hello.jar" could not be launched. Check the Console for possible error or messages.

I have searched online quite a bit and all the recommendations are the obvious solutions of calling java from a shell script or wrapping the jar file into a native executable. For this particular question, I want to limit the discussion to how can I execute the jar file on macOS by double clicking on the jar file
itself  *without* modifying the jar file?

I have tried the test with two types of Java applications - a command line one and a GUI one.

**Command Line Application**:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, please enter some input");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scan.next();
        System.out.println(s);
        scan.close();
    }

}
```

I am then compiling and bundling with the following commands:

```
javac Hello.java
jar cvfe Hello.jar Hello Hello.class
```

**GUI Application**:

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FileChooserExample extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
        System.out.println(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```

This is compiled in the same manner as the command line application. Interestingly, the GUI one works when double clicking on Windows but has the error on macOS. **How can I execute the jar file on macOS by double clicking on the jar file itself *without* modifying the jar file?**

**EDIT**: I am also not able to load any other executable on the system, outside of Java if the system does not already have it installed. I am preferably looking for a way to do this via configuration of the system using any standard Java distribution (e.g., OpenJDK, Oracle, etc.).

Comment: I found that with only the old Java 8 installed, and some permissions granted (give Full Disk Access to JavaLauncher via: Settings->Security & Privacy->Full Disk Access and add /System/Library/CoreServices/JavaLauncher), that I could double-click a .jar file and it would launch using javalauncher just fine. After the java app was recompiled for Java 11, this could no longer be done--just get the error you mentioned.

Comment: When compiled using Java 11 JRE, you can set the language level down at Java 8, so that Java 8 JRE's can execute it.   Or upgrade your JRE to Java 11 (or 17) on your laptop, so that it can handle a variety of newer compiled codes.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple [document based app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/documents_data_and_pasteboard/developing_a_document-based_app) that receives a jar file and executes it with the java command.

Once you have that , follow these steps to make it the handler when double-clicking a jar file:

1. Select any jar file in Finder.
2. Right click it and select "get info"
3. Under "open with" , select your jar-opener app and click "change all" so that this new selection applies to all jars.

Note that the selection dialog for the app to open with is initially limited to "recommended apps". There's a combo box at the bottom that allows you to change it to "all applicaitons"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What I am hoping for is a way to do this without loading any other code on the system. In other words, I am looking for a way to do this just via configuration. Is there a way to set the Java Launcher App to just run the jar file in the same way it would execute via java -jar Hello.jar?

Comment: What is the "jar opener app?"