# how to open a jar file with double click instead of terminal on Mac

Tags: java

I write basic java programs for fun, and unfortunately I cannot run their jar files with double clicking. However, I can open jar files through terminal with no issue. could you please explain to me the issue and how to fix it? I reordered my screen and uploaded it on YouTube if you want to see what happens when I click on a jar file:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pyh5k2w_o1s

Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: I think this is more about computer *use* rather than about programming (the fact that you wrote the program is just incidental), but then again I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63320019/macos-launch-jar-file-by-double-clicking) in case someone thinks this is a duplicate rather than OT.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881858/13257777

by script let use:

```
java -jar path_to_Lab15.jar
```

Answer (score -2):

Downloading a Java Runtime Environment can do the trick.

For future projects you may want to checkout [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). It is a tool to convert your runnable .jar file to an .exe.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am a Mac user, is there any similar solution for Mac?

Comment: btw when I type Java -version in terminal, I get :

java  -version
java version "1.8.0_331"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_331-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.331-b09, mixed mode)

So I think I have JRE installed. Am I correct?

Comment: yes you are correct. You got one of the newest JRE installed.
Unfortunately I don't know about a similar solution for Mac. I'm sorry.